# Rails 3 -rendering partials and error "undefined local variable or method"

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, view, render, partial

I have a photos in gallery (**PhotosController**) and I wanna add to every photo a comments. Into the statement of photos I added a partial for rendering comments + form for adding new comment.

My problem is, that when I send the form with a new comment, so I'll get the rendering error:

```
**NameError (undefined local variable or method `photo' for #<CommentsController:0x00000100ce0ad0>)**:
```

This is how looks my code:

**views/photos/index.html.erb**

```
<%= render @photos %>
```

**views/photos/_photo.html.erb**

```
<div><%=image_tag photo.photo.url(:thumb)%></div>
<div class="comments_to_photo">
  <%= render :partial => 'photos/photo_comments', :locals => { :photo => photo }%>
</div>
```

**photos/photo_comments**

```
<%photo.comments.each do |cmnt|%>
  <div><%=cmnt.comment%></div>
<%end%> 

<%=form_tag comment_path, :remote => true do %>
  <div><%=text_area_tag 'comment[comment]'%></div>
  <%=submit_tag%>
<%end%>
```

**controllers/CommentsController**

```
  def create
    @comment = Comment.new(params[:comment])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @comment.save
        format.html { redirect_to @comment, notice: 'Comment was successfully created.' }
        format.js {
          render :partial => '/photos/photo_comments', :locals => { :photo => photo } do |page|; page << "$(this).html('abcde');" end  
        }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.js
      end
    end
  end
```

I would like to refresh the form and comments statement in the photo, where was added a comment. Could anyone help me, please, how to avoid the error above?

Thank you in advance

**EDIT:** I added for refresh comments through AJAX the file **_photo_comments.js.erb**:

```
$('#photo_comment').html("<%= escape_javascript(render('photos/photo_comments')) %>");
```

And I get the error

```
ActionView::Template::Error (stack level too deep):
  activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:23
```

with tens of this line:

```
  Rendered photos/_photo_comments.js.erb (562.2ms)
```

and the last one

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 580ms
```

What's wrong with rendering? I can't render partial html file from partial JS file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your controller you have:

```
:locals => { :photo => photo }
```

but the variable `photo` doesn't exist there. It should be:

```
:locals => { :photo => @comment.photo }
```

Comment: thank you, this solve my problem. I tried to render through AJAX the statement of comments, but I got the error "stack level too deep" - have you any idea, what I could forgot? (I updated my question). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`image_tag photo.photo.url(:thumb)` <- Is it what you want to have `photo.photo` ?

Comment: Yes, because I have in the table **Photos** are columns **photo_file_name**, **photo_content_type** - this is right, the images are displayed right, but when I want to render partials by AJAX, I am getting the error above...